# How to add tableau embedded code in my website using by oauth2.0 . i am trying to create jwt sign in api but its showing error

Tags: authentication, tableau-api

We are trying to integrate tableau dashboard in our website using by Connected Apps with OAuth 2.0 Trust. i am creating connected app in tableau dashboard and getting client id , site id and other information . after that i am creating jwt token using by connected app details.
i am following document is - https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/connected_apps_eas.htm
after that we are passing jwt token in sign in api .
my api curl is -

```
`curl --location '{server-url}/api/3.20/auth/signin' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--data '<tsRequest>
    <credentials jwt="{jwt-token}">
        <site contentUrl="{content-url}"/>
    </credentials>
</tsRequest>'
```

`
after that its showing error

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api https://help.tableau.com/samples/en-us/rest_api/ts-api_3_20.xsd">
    <error code="401001">
        <summary>Signin Error</summary>
        <detail>Error signing in to Tableau Server</detail>
    </error>
</tsResponse>`
```

i am not finding what issue in this jwt token.
Thanks in advance for answering

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify how you are intending to use the Tableau Connected App integration?

If you want to embed Tableau content on a website or app then you would need to pass the JWT to the web component as described here: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/docs/embedding_api_auth.html

If you want to use Tableau's REST API then you need to include the JWT in the request body of the Sign In method as shown here: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_authentication.htm#jwt

Don't forget to use the API key found in the response to this request to authenticate subsequent REST API calls with that session key